# Jasmin assembler using array assignment satements

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm, jasmin

```
var a int[1];
var aa int[1];
aa = a;
```

Suppose we wanted to compile something like this in java jvm.  It would seam that one would just do a

```
ldc 1
newarray    int
astore  0
ldc 1
newarray    int
astore  1
aload   0
istore  1
```

However this is not work it is throwing a `(class: test, method: main signature: ()V) Expecting to find integer on stack` Can you not `aload` an array into a local variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `istore` instruction causing the problem. In the [Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.istore) it's defined to

> Store int into local variable

You're trying to store the array reference, so `astore` is the correct instruction type, just the way you did it after the `newarray` instructions.